# Kendo UI MVC - DatePickerFor not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a ASP.Net MVC Razor page that uses a Kendo UI date-picker using the **DatePickerFor** Kendo MVC extension.

The culture info in my region requires the date format to be **dd/MM/yyyy**.

If I use dd/MM/yyyy then a date with a single digit for the day won't bind e.g. 1 August 2014.

However, if I use d/MM/yyyy then a date with two digits for the day won't bind e.g. 31 August 2014.

This appears to be a bug in Kendo UI.  Does anybody know a work-around?

**Update (more diagnosis):** It appears the problem is the culture.  12 August 2014 binds because it is interpreting it at 8 December 2014.

**Update (code samples, both give same result):**

*Using Format:*

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.To, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.To).Culture(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.To)
            </div>
        </div>
```

*Using Culture:*

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.To, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.To).Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString())
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.To)
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Update (more info):** Just to clarify, the binding issue is when submitting the form...binding works fine when the form is first loaded

Comment: please provide some code that you have done so far

Comment: More info and code samples provided

Comment: your question provided an answer i was looking for :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a typo (copy-paste mistake).  The form was using a GET instead of a POST.